# Unify refugees and asylum tags?

Tags: discussion

The [refugees](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refugees) tag currently has 30 questions with a large overlap to [asylum](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asylum) questions. Can we merge the two tags?

Answer (score 5):

There's a [slight difference between the two](https://www.amnesty.org.au/refugee-and-an-asylum-seeker-difference/):

> ### Asylum seeker
>
> An asylum seeker is an individual who is seeking international
>   protection. In countries with individualised procedures, an asylum
>   seeker is someone whose claim has not yet been finally decided on by
>   the country in which he or she has submitted it. Not every asylum
>   seeker will ultimately be recognised as a refugee, but every refugee
>   is initially an asylum seeker.
>
> ### Refugee
>
> A refugee is a person who has fled their country of origin and is
>   unable or unwilling to return because of a well-founded fear of being
>   persecuted because of their race, religion, nationality, membership of
>   a particular social group or political opinion.

Just to add a little bit of detail to clarify the difference: an asylum seeker can also be a [displaced person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_displacement) -- but not an economic migrant.

Comment: Sure, but that's a very technical distinction that's not understood by most users of the site. A lot of questions use both tags interchangeably. Therefore I propose merging the tags to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JonathanReez: The distinction isn't technical IMHO. Also, I presume you're the one who downvoted my answer. FYI I'm the only one who upvoted your question so far...

Comment: I downvoted it because I don't believe the distinction to be significant enough for the site to have two tags, that's all

Comment: @JonathanReez: Well, I upvoted your question because I believe you bring up an interesting point -- indeed they do get confused in popular discourse. I simply wanted to raise that, actually, there's a subtle but very real difference between the two. Side note: there is no `displaced` tag or equivalent.

Comment: @JonathanReez note that this distinction could be clarified in the tag excerpts.

Comment: Well an asylum *seeker* can be an economic migrant (as well). Not only asylum requests are denied in large proportion because of the latter reason, but even those which are granted don't *exclude* that an economic reason might exist; it just means that there are just *more compelling* reasons to grant the asylum request (e.g. genuine persecution).